# Why JPA + TransactionManagementConfigurer doesn't work

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, transactionmanager

With JPA in Spring4, I'd like to define a `default` TransactionManager, so in my `@Configuration` class I implements interface `TransactionManagementConfigurer` and Override method `annotationDrivenTransactionManager`--- it return JPA-TX. But when I start my app I got a confused Error:

```
    2017-02-14 15:00:19.108 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1022) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054) ~[spring-context-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829) ~[spring-context-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444) ~[spring-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326) [spring-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4937) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_45]
```

What does the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException` mean.

This is the config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"cn.madmind.config"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"cn.madmind.config"})
public class RootApplicationConfig implements TransactionManagementConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource datasource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        datasource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        datasource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/alioth");
        datasource.setUsername("root");
        datasource.setPassword("");
        return datasource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return jpaTransactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        adapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(adapter);
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.setPackagesToScan("cn.madmind.config");
        return factory;
    }

    /**
     * set default transaction-manager
     */
    @Override
    public PlatformTransactionManager annotationDrivenTransactionManager() {
        return transactionManager();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible it's a bug in the Spring Framework itself: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10787

I'm facing a similar issue currently though, in versions of the framework that's theoretically fixed (4.1.9.RELEASE and 4.3.9.RELEASE), so your milage may vary.

Edit: It seems our project had some questionable autowiring around @Imported @Configuration, (a few spuriously static bean factory methods, 
and directly autowired fields) that flew for old versions of Spring, but broke during an attempted upgrade.

Tidying that up, separating out the concerns a little, ensuring I was doing constructor injection of Configuration files like the docs suggest: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html fixed it for me.